# VBA Excel, Game Component?

Tags: excel, vba, function, api, 2d-games

I was researching different components of VBA and APIs and came across a [website](http://ericphelps.com/pong/index.htm) that proposes a personalized API that runs the game Pong within a spreadsheet that contains certain subs and functions.  The instance used was with Windows/Excel version 97 and is stated to not be compatible with the 2000 version (and, I am assuming, the current version).  I was wondering if any VBA-savvy individuals who thought this was worth doing could let me know whether this is a function capable of implementing under the current iteration of Excel, and if so, what the workaround would be?

When I use the following code below, I get a run-time error declaring that

> `vba332.dll` is missing

the debugger highlights the 9th line of the `Public Function AddrOf` which states:
`Call GetCurrentVbaProject (hProject)`
 is the error line and `(hProject)` when hovered on is `0`, which I am assuming is also a problem as it is supposed to be getting a value other than 0 to move forward...

According to some reading that I have found, the newer version of the referenced .dll would be something like:

```
vbe7.dll
```

But when I have substituted that line within this string of codes, it still does not return any data for the Declare Function.

This seemed like a fun API to play around with, but I could not devise a way to upgrade it to the current Excel version. The code:

```
Option Explicit

Private Declare Function GetCurrentVbaProject _
Lib "vba332.dll" Alias "EbGetExecutingProj" _
(hProject As Long) As Long

Private Declare Function GetFuncID Lib "vba332.dll" Alias "TipGetFunctionId" _
(ByVal hProject As Long, ByVal strFunctionName As String, _
ByRef strFunctionId As String) As Long

Private Declare Function GetAddr _
Lib "vba332.dll" Alias "TipGetLpfnOfFunctionId" _
(ByVal hProject As Long, ByVal strFunctionId As String, _
ByRef lpfn As Long) As Long
Private Declare Function SetTimer Lib "user32" _
(ByVal hwnd As Long, ByVal nIDEvent As Long, _
ByVal uElapse As Long, ByVal lpTimerFunc As Long) As Long
Private Declare Function KillTimer Lib "user32" _
(ByVal hwnd As Long, ByVal nIDEvent As Long) As Long

Private lngTimerId As Long
Dim Paddle As Shape
Dim Ball As Shape
Dim nVertical As Integer
Dim nHorizontal As Integer
Dim nSpeed As Integer

Sub Auto_Open()
Application.OnKey "{F12}", "StartPong"
End Sub

Sub Auto_Close()
Timer_Terminate
On Error Resume Next
Paddle.Delete
Ball.Delete
End Sub

Sub StartPong()
Dim nLeft As Integer
Dim nTop As Integer
Dim nWidth As Integer
Dim nHeight As Integer
'Draw the paddle
nLeft = ActiveWindow.UsableWidth - 100
nTop = ActiveWindow.UsableHeight - 30
nWidth = 50
nHeight = 10
Set Paddle = ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddShape(1, nLeft, nTop, nWidth, nHeight)
Paddle.Fill.ForeColor.SchemeColor = 8
'Draw the ball
nLeft = CInt(ActiveWindow.UsableWidth / 2) - 20
nTop = 0
nWidth = 15
nHeight = 15
Set Ball = ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddShape(9, nLeft, nTop, nWidth, nHeight)
Ball.Fill.ForeColor.SchemeColor = 8
'Define keys
Application.OnKey "{ESC}", "EndPong"
Application.OnKey "{RIGHT}", "MoveRight"
Application.OnKey "{LEFT}", "MoveLeft"
Application.OnKey "{F12}"
'Set speed
nVertical = 10   'Ball Vertical
nHorizontal = 10 'Ball Horizontal
nSpeed = 18      'Paddle Horizontal
'Start the ball movement timer
Timer_Initialize (15) 'Ball will be moved every 15 milliseconds
'Now we wait for events to move things
End Sub

Sub MoveBall()
Dim nLeft As Integer
Dim nTop As Integer

With Ball
    'Move Horizontal
    .Left = .Left + nHorizontal
    'Move vertical
    .Top = .Top + nVertical
    'Bounce horizontal
    nLeft = .Left
    If nLeft > (ActiveWindow.UsableWidth - 50) Then
        nHorizontal = -1 * Abs((nHorizontal))
    End If
    If nLeft < 20 Then
        nHorizontal = Abs(nHorizontal)
    End If
    'Bounce vertical
    nTop = .Top
    If nTop > (ActiveWindow.UsableHeight - 50) Then
        nVertical = -1 * (Abs(nVertical))
        'Did Paddle hit it?
        If (.Left + (.Width / 2)) > Paddle.Left And _
           (.Left + (.Width / 2)) < (Paddle.Left + Paddle.Width) Then
            'Paddle hit the ball
            If (.Left + (.Width / 2)) < (Paddle.Left + (Paddle.Width / 3)) Then
                'Ball hit paddle on left third; apply english
                nHorizontal = nHorizontal - 5
                If nHorizontal < -15 Then nHorizontal = -15
            End If
            If (.Left + (.Width / 2)) > (Paddle.Left + (2 * Paddle.Width / 3)) Then
                'Ball hit paddle on right third
                nHorizontal = nHorizontal + 5
                If nHorizontal > 15 Then nHorizontal = 15
            End If
        Else
            Beep 'missed
            'Move the paddle in case window was resized
            Paddle.Top = ActiveWindow.UsableHeight - 30
        End If
    End If
    If nTop < 20 Then
        nVertical = Abs(nVertical)
    End If

End With
End Sub

Sub EndPong()
Timer_Terminate
Application.OnKey "{ESC}"
Application.OnKey "{RIGHT}"
Application.OnKey "{LEFT}"
Application.OnKey "{F12}", "StartPong"
Paddle.Delete
Ball.Delete
End Sub


Sub MoveRight()
Paddle.Left = Paddle.Left + nSpeed
If Paddle.Left > (Application.UsableWidth - 30 - Paddle.Width) Then
    Paddle.Left = Application.UsableWidth - 30 - Paddle.Width
End If
End Sub

Sub MoveLeft()
Paddle.Left = Paddle.Left - nSpeed
If Paddle.Left < 0 Then
    Paddle.Left = 0
End If
End Sub

Public Function AddrOf(strFuncName As String) As Long
'Returns a function pointer of a VBA public function given its name.
'AddrOf code from Microsoft Office Developer magazine
'http://www.informant.com/mod/index.htm
 Dim hProject As Long
 Dim lngResult As Long
 Dim strID As String
 Dim lpfn As Long
 Dim strFuncNameUnicode As String
 Const NO_ERROR = 0
' The function name must be in Unicode, so convert it.
strFuncNameUnicode = StrConv(strFuncName, vbUnicode)
' Get the current VBA project
Call GetCurrentVbaProject(hProject)
' Make sure we got a project handle
If hProject <> 0 Then
    ' Get the VBA function ID
    lngResult = GetFuncID(hProject, strFuncNameUnicode, strID)
    If lngResult = NO_ERROR Then
        ' Get the function pointer.
        lngResult = GetAddr(hProject, strID, lpfn)
        If lngResult = NO_ERROR Then
            AddrOf = lpfn
        End If
    End If
End If
End Function

Private Sub TimerProc(ByVal hwnd&, ByVal lngMsg&, ByVal lngTimerId&, ByVal    
lngTime&)
Call MoveBall
End Sub

Sub Timer_Initialize(Optional vInterval As Variant)
Dim lngInterval As Long
lngInterval = CLng(vInterval)
If lngInterval = 0 Then lngInterval = 60 '60 milliseconds just a bit longer   
than a "tick"
lngTimerId = SetTimer(0, 0, lngInterval, AddrOf("TimerProc"))
If lngTimerId = 0 Then
    MsgBox "Unable to initialize a new timer!"
End If
End Sub

Sub Timer_Terminate()
If lngTimerId <> 0 Then
    Call KillTimer(0, lngTimerId)
End If
End Sub
```

Thanks!

Comment: The error message seems very clear: `the file "vba332.dll" is missing`. Have you this `.dll` library into your `System32` folder?

Comment: P.s.: _I get a run-time error_.... are you sure? If the library is missing, it should not compile at all. Are you sure is not a compile error? If yes, do you maybe remove the line causing the error (which is clearly not the good idea)?

Comment: @MatteoNNZ, I think that is a very old, very outdated dll and not likely to be on any of our systems (not even the old ones donated to libraries, schools or churches). My interpretation of the OPs question is `What is necessary to update this to run on a modern system`, which means someone needs to look up the functions used from `vba332.dll` and find their modern equivalents and replace the calls.

Comment: @FreeMan right, just seen that on the website it's written "for Microsoft Excel 97".

Answer (score 1):

In later versions of Office, "TipGetLpfnOfFunctionId" is exposed as AddressOf.

And since you can use AddressOf directly to get the address of a function, you don't need "TipGetFunctionId" nor all the "addrof" code.

```
Sub Timer_Initialize(Optional vInterval As Variant)
Dim lngInterval As Long
  lngInterval = CLng(vInterval)
  If lngInterval = 0 Then lngInterval = 60   
  lngTimerId = SetTimer(0, 0, lngInterval, AddressOf TimerProc)
  If lngTimerId = 0 Then
    MsgBox "Unable to initialize a new timer!"
  End If
End Sub
```

Note the unique syntax of the "AddressOf" operator: it's not a function.